# Python.NET: How to access generic member of an interface

Tags: python, c#, python.net, flaui

I am trying to use a generic member from an interface in FlaUI through Python.NET.

The below C# code works,

```
// myLegacyTreeItem is a valid AutomationElement
// this works and the default action expands the tree node
myLegacyTreeItem.Patterns.LegacyIAccessible.Pattern.DoDefaultAction();
```

However, the below corresponding Python.NET code doesn't work,

```
# my_legacy_tree_item is a valid element
my_legacy_tree_item.Patterns.LegacyIAccessible.Pattern.DoDefaultAction()
```

I am getting the following error,

```
AttributeError: 'UIA3FrameworkAutomationElement' object has no attribute 'LegacyIAccessible'
```

I can see the the `LegacyIAccessible` member is using generic syntax. But I am not able to figure out how to bind it to the concrete type.

https://github.com/FlaUI/FlaUI/blob/master/src/FlaUI.Core/FrameworkAutomationElementBase.Patterns.cs

```
using FlaUI.Core.Patterns;

namespace FlaUI.Core
{
    public abstract partial class FrameworkAutomationElementBase : FrameworkAutomationElementBase.IFrameworkPatterns
    {
        private IAutomationPattern<IAnnotationPattern> _annotationPattern;
        private IAutomationPattern<IDockPattern> _dockPattern;
        private IAutomationPattern<IDragPattern> _dragPattern;
        private IAutomationPattern<IDropTargetPattern> _dropTargetPattern;
        private IAutomationPattern<IExpandCollapsePattern> _expandCollapsePattern;
        private IAutomationPattern<IGridItemPattern> _gridItemPattern;
        private IAutomationPattern<IGridPattern> _gridPattern;
        private IAutomationPattern<IInvokePattern> _invokePattern;
        private IAutomationPattern<IItemContainerPattern> _itemContainerPattern;
        private IAutomationPattern<ILegacyIAccessiblePattern> _legacyIAccessiblePattern;
        ...
        public IFrameworkPatterns Patterns => this;

        IAutomationPattern<IAnnotationPattern> IFrameworkPatterns.Annotation => _annotationPattern ?? (_annotationPattern = InitializeAnnotationPattern());
        IAutomationPattern<IDockPattern> IFrameworkPatterns.Dock => _dockPattern ?? (_dockPattern = InitializeDockPattern());
        IAutomationPattern<IDragPattern> IFrameworkPatterns.Drag => _dragPattern ?? (_dragPattern = InitializeDragPattern());
        IAutomationPattern<IDropTargetPattern> IFrameworkPatterns.DropTarget => _dropTargetPattern ?? (_dropTargetPattern = InitializeDropTargetPattern());
        IAutomationPattern<IExpandCollapsePattern> IFrameworkPatterns.ExpandCollapse => _expandCollapsePattern ?? (_expandCollapsePattern = InitializeExpandCollapsePattern());
        IAutomationPattern<IGridItemPattern> IFrameworkPatterns.GridItem => _gridItemPattern ?? (_gridItemPattern = InitializeGridItemPattern());
        IAutomationPattern<IGridPattern> IFrameworkPatterns.Grid => _gridPattern ?? (_gridPattern = InitializeGridPattern());
        IAutomationPattern<IInvokePattern> IFrameworkPatterns.Invoke => _invokePattern ?? (_invokePattern = InitializeInvokePattern());
        IAutomationPattern<IItemContainerPattern> IFrameworkPatterns.ItemContainer => _itemContainerPattern ?? (_itemContainerPattern = InitializeItemContainerPattern());
        IAutomationPattern<ILegacyIAccessiblePattern> IFrameworkPatterns.LegacyIAccessible => _legacyIAccessiblePattern ?? (_legacyIAccessiblePattern = InitializeLegacyIAccessiblePattern());
        ...
    }
}
```

If I change the call as below, there is no error, but the tree item is not expanded,

```
((FrameworkAutomationElementBase.IFrameworkPatterns)(my_legacy_tree_item.Patterns)).LegacyIAccessible.Pattern.DoDefaultAction()
```

Trying to use the below cast throws error,

```
((FrameworkAutomationElementBase.IFrameworkPatterns[ILegacyIAccessiblePattern])(parent.Patterns)).LegacyIAccessible.Pattern.DoDefaultAction()
```

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Python.Runtime.GenericUtil.GenericByName(String ns, String name, Int32 paramCount)
   at Python.Runtime.ClassBase.type_subscript(IntPtr idx)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question as it was a silly mistake.

The below line indeed expands the legacy tree item,

```
((FrameworkAutomationElementBase.IFrameworkPatterns)(my_legacy_tree_item.Patterns)).LegacyIAccessible.Pattern.DoDefaultAction()
```

However, since in my case, I was also immediately right clicking on the same item, the context menu was getting popped up before the tree item could be expanded. So adding `sleep(1)` after the above call worked for me.

Alternatively `my_legacy_tree_item.DoubleClick()` followed by `sleep(1)` worked too.